# How to get input file value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code :

```
<input className='input-file' type='file' onChange={this.handleDocumentUploadChange(index)} />
```

while `index` is a pre-given int. The problem is that i'd like to read the value of the this element, but i cant. I've tried to access the `event.target.value` but it stays null. Any ideas ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-input - Check that out

Comment: Try “FileReader” API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried passing like this? `this.handleDocumentUploadChange(this, index)`

Comment: my methods takes parameter, therefore i dont seem to be able to access the to event object inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the problem.

My input was rendered in a .map() function. Therefore when i wanted to bind with `this` such as `onChange={this.handleDocumentTitleChange.bind(this, index)}` it wouldnt work.

So instead i did this `var self = this;` and binded into `self` instead.

Comment: `[].map()` takes a 2nd parameter, `this`; you might notice it used in loops in many of the react examples, and it would prevent the need to bind anything or alias `this`. so, `.map(fn, this)`...